# Ext4 partition clockworkmod recovery backup

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery, zte-blade, ext4, ext3

Successfully installed CM7 on ZTE Blade and simple2ext ([S2E](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.krikun.s2e)) made me excited.
I've partitioned my SD in CWM recovery and I guess it was Ext3 partition.
But one thing was mistake. I have checked in S2E checkbox says `mount sd-ext partition as Ext4` and everything was okay until I wanted to make backup from recovery.
All part passed succesfully but `/sd-ext` and I've googled [this thread says](http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1323629.html):

> "clockworkmod doesn't support ext4 on the blade. ext3 works."

Unticking that checkbox makes all unworkable.

What can I do now to make ext-partition to ext3 back and backup it succesfully by recovery?

At this moment I want to make wipe or hard or factory reset to check something with clean android installation and then go back to my phone's current state.
Maybe it's no need to make partition from ext4 to be ext3?

ROM: CyanogenMod-7.2.0-RC1-blade-KANG (2.3.7 by BurgerZ)
Kernel: 2.6.35.7-perf+

Comment: Not a specific Android question (rather file-system specific) -- but in short: That seems to be a no-go. See [Convert an ext4 partition to ext3 without formatting the HDD](http://serverfault.com/questions/289829/convert-an-ext4-partition-to-ext3-without-formatting-the-hdd) at Server Fault. *PS:* You might want to flag your question for migration to serverfault.

Comment: Think you should be asking that specific question over on [modaco](http://blade.modaco.com) under *ROMs & ROM Customization*

Comment: thank you all for the replies. I gone by longest way and all is okay now. It's not convenient way to tell it here. But thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: If you have TWRP recovery for your device, try replacing CWM with it. It supports ext4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most secure way:

1. Backup all apps with their data with TitaniumBackup. Backup all data from sdcard.
2. Delete some apps to free space on device's memory.
3. Check if all transfer-checkboxes in s2e are available now. If not - free up some more space.
4. Transfer ALL apps, data etc back to device's memory in s2e.
5. Format sdcard again with setting sd-ext partition size bigger or equal than current.
6. Restore all data to sdcard.
7. Reconfigure s2e WITHOUT ticking "mount as ext4" option!
8. Restore all apps in TitaniumBackup.

Please, be very careful. I'm not responding for any damage or data loss.

Please, correct me if something missed or excess here.