# ROMManager does not backup my sd-ext

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery, partitions, rom-manager

I am using rooted LG P500 running stock 2.3.3. Recently I partitioned my SD card using ROMManager in to three partitions (swap, ext and usb storage). I checked with [Mini Partition Tool](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) and understood that the sd-ext type is ext3. Link2SD created mount script and linked apps perfectly, releasing loads of space in memory.

To try an unofficial CM10 ROM, I backed up using ROMManager (NAndroid) and installed the unofficial CM10 ROM.  While using CM10, I wiped sd-ext partition and linked few apps with belief that backup is done. Since I was unhappy with the CM10 ROM I decided to restore the backup and while doing so only I observed that my sd-ext partition contents were not backed up.

Thinking that I might not have backed up properly, I tried again to back up in restored backup of stock 2.3.3 and observed a message:

> "Could not mount sd-ext. sd-ext backup may not be supported on this device. Skipping backup of sd-ext"

Had if I had noticed this message, I would not have installed the CM10 ROM at all.

**Question:** How can I make ROMManager to backup sd-ext partitions as well? I guess just because it was unable to mount, it just skipped sd-ext backup. When Link2SD was able to mount, what is stopping ROMManager to mount it and how can I fix it?

Info:

1. I tried this with ClockworkMod Recovery version 5.0.2.7 and ROMManager version is 5.0.2.1
2. I have seen the question "[Ext4 partition clockworkmod recovery backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27797/ext4-partition-clockworkmod-recovery-backup)" and this question differs because the partition used is ext3 and was created by ROMMananger itself.

**Update:**

1. I have seen this [modaco forum thread](http://www.modaco.com/topic/347926-clockworkmod-recovery-could-not-mount-sd-ext-sd-ext-backup-may-not-be-supported-on-this-device/) and it just only helped me to come to a assumption that my present recovery version 5.0.2.7 does not support it. I will be glad to confirm it either from any authoritative source or burst the myth if some other user successfully backed up (either with 5.0.2.7) sd-ext.
2. When I attempted to use "mount and storage -> mount /sd-ext" option in CWM recovery console, I just get "Error mounting /sd-ext!" message.

Comment: Have you fixed this problem?

Comment: Not yet. I noticed few XDA threads claim Amon Ra recovery manager can backup sd-ext partition. As of now I haven't tried it yet. I also observed that my Rom manager fails to mount the partition through one of the menu options in recovery mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion that ROM Manager doesn't support sd-ext backup is quite confirmed with my experience. While looking for alternatives, I understood that there are these three recoveries available:

1. [Clockwork Mod recovery](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager) (CWM)
2. [Amon Ra](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Amon_Ra_recovery_tool) recovery
3. [TeamWin recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1888926) (TWRP)

I tried the TWRP 2.2.2.1 from its [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1888926) and I am glad to inform that it did back up my ext3 partition. Other than this benefit, I have a touch interface which is much easier in par with CMW's user interface.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is described e.g. in [this modaco forum thread](http://www.modaco.com/topic/347926-clockworkmod-recovery-could-not-mount-sd-ext-sd-ext-backup-may-not-be-supported-on-this-device/). In case of that user, the `sd-ext` partition got corrupted as it was mounted wrongly by the Android system (he used [GPartEd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to create his partitions which, regardless of the filesystem created (`ext2/3/4`, `fat32`), then were mounted as `ext4`).

So what he basically did: He factory reset the phone, deleted the partitions on SDCard, recreated them *on phone* (i.e. not with the card mounted to any PC, but *directly on the phone*, using CWMs options as far as I understood).

I didn't try that solution myself, as I'm not affected by the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, I already saw it and recreated partitions using CWM as described. I posted this question after this attempt only.

Comment: Oh. Couldn't know that -- sorry to hear it didn't help in your case. Guess I still leave the answer here in the hope it might prove helpful to others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

To backup sd-ext

REQUIREMETS:

1. Device should be rooted
2. Root Explorer
3. Brain

Steps:

1. Open root explorer
2. Now go to root>data
3. The will be a folder names sdext 2
4. Open it
5. Copy all the the contents of sdext2 folder and paste it in your sd card

Here it is,now you have a backup of your sd-ext

TO RESTORE SD-EXT

1. Copy all the contents which we have backuped in previous steps
2. Now go to root>data
3. Now find sdext folder and open it
4. Now paste all the contents we had copied in the step1

Here it is,we have restored over sd-ext

Answer (score -1):

I Think that CWM is not able to detect sd-ext because it is not mounted as"/sd-ext" but instead as "/data/sd-ext" by link2sd. But I do not know in detail abot Android Working  I cant fix it.